# JQuery to collapse table?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm running the MyBB forum software and was able to load jQuery without breaking the functionality. The board itself already has a collapse function but I would like to do it in jquery, or well add a nice jquery effect to it, more smoother.

http://craftedbyfrank.com

At the moment when the [+] and [-] images are clicked the table collapses and shows.

I'm trying the following but having no luck.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">                                         
  $(document).ready(function() {
  $("tr.thead").click(function () { 
  $("tr.thead.img", $(this).parent()).slideToggle("fast");
   });


});
</script>
```

I loaded jQuery 1.9

All help is appreciated.

Comment: Please post relevant code here and not on another site. External sites can change and make the post of no value to future visitors. For more information, see [Questions linking to external web sites instead of showing code](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/80978/1976560).

Comment: Tell me about this: tr.thead.img   is .img a class?  Is .thead a class too?  Why are you using classes that are identical in name to elements?  Did you mean tr thead img?

Comment: Might jQuery UI accordion be what you're looking for? http://jqueryui.com/accordion/

Comment: Sorry about adding the code to an external site, I was trying to add it but it kept breaking or not showing the full code here.

Comment: The thead class is where the collapse button is found, the img [+] and [-] can be found there. Just a bit confuse in general.

Comment: make sure you add a return before you put code and then add 4 spaces to each line that you want to display code in. Please edit with the code used :)

Comment: Alright, I have updated the post.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're conflicting with another library. Try using 'jQuery' instead of '$'.

This is working, though I'm seeing dual actions due to existing code:

```
jQuery('.expcolimage').click(function () { 
  jQuery(this).parents('table').find('tbody').slideToggle();
});
```

Comment: I've replaced my old code and added this one but no change. :/

Comment: Sorry, I have not. I'm having trouble finding the library it's calling. I can try changing the class name if that would help?

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">                                         
  $(document).ready(function() {
  $("tr.thead").click(function () { 
  $(this).find('td').slideToggle("fast");
   });


});
</script>
```